# Can someone tell me the meaning of this line?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```rb
return unless children.count.positive?
```

It would be very helpfull if you give me examples of how to use unless and if in rails

Comment: I'm not sure what you are actually expecting in your answer. `if` and `unless` are ruby things and not rails specifc, and a quick google will yield multiple results explaining it. What exactly is unclear to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `unless` keyword in Ruby is just the opposite of the `if` keyword. This means that whereas `if` executes the code if the statement is true, `unless` executes the code if the statement is not true.

For your example, the code returns if `children.count` returns a negative number.

Answer (score 0):

An extra simple example could be:

```rb
if true
  puts 'this is definitely printed!.'
end
```

```rb
unless false
  puts 'this is definitely printed!.'
end
```

Running both code snippets you will get two lines of output with the same string telling `this is definitely printed!.`.